# How to Connect My iPhone app to tv through hdmi Cable

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement where i need to connect my iPhone to TV through HDMI Cable and play the videos on TV.

how to detect that hdmi cable is connected to iPhone.Are there any delegate methods?

Can anyone give the reference notes for this.....

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Reference notes : Apple's development documentation.

Comment: thanks Nick.....i knew apples documentation.....is there anything more u can help me in this issue

Comment: And what's wrong with Apple's documentation?

Comment: i didn't found anything related to hdmi connection delegate methods...thats the reason i posted this.....but sure i will find some more information and edit my question..Thanks once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a link, in french, but you can go trough the code to understand it.

http://www.benoit-deldicque.com/blog/utiliser-une-tv-avec-iphone-ipad-hdmi-adapter-et-ios-sdk/

Comment: you are welcome, mark your question as solved if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the specific cable for your model iPhone and model TV for this to work. Also it is not a exact mirror of your iPhone it uses only photo apps and video apps.

http://connect-to-tv.blogspot.com/2014/02/connect-iphone-to-your-tv.html